# Disable Elixir Ecto Debug output

Tags: debugging, elixir, ecto

Whatever in `iex>` or using `mix run -e "My.code"` when I run the mix project using ecto, the Ecto's Debugging Mechanism display a bunch of SQLs like below

```
16:42:12.870 [debug] SELECT a0.`id` FROM `account` AS a0 WHERE (a0.`account_name` = ?) ["71000000313"] (39.6ms)`
...
```

When I dont need the debug output anymore, How can I turn it off, I cannot find anything about how to change ecto log level stuff.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your logging level is configured in your `config/#{env}.exs` files. If you look into `config/prod.exs` it most likely already has that level set to `:info`:

```
config :logger, level: :info
```

So if you run the app with `MIX_ENV=prod iex -S mix` you won't get the debug output. This means that when you build a release with something like `MIX_ENV=prod mix release` the resulting build won't be producing this output. Alternatively you may set `level: :info` or `:warn` for whatever environment you want by changing the appropriate `config/#{env}.exs`.

Answer (score 38):

If you want to change the `Ecto` (pre 2.0) log level (and only it) then you can use the `log_level` configuration option that can be set in your applications Ecto repository configuration.
In example:

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  database: "my_app",
  username: "my_app",
  password: "secret",
  hostname: "localhost",
  port: 5433,
  log_level: :info
```

Of course beside the above you can always change the [`Logger`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/logger/) configuration log `level` option if you want to change the overall log level (not only the `Ecto` log level) e.g.:

`config :logger, level: :info`

**Update (by [@Milos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30297825/disable-elixir-ecto-debug-output/30319577?noredirect=1#comment58904100_30319577)):**

Since Ecto 2.0.0, instead of `log_level: :info` you need to use `loggers: [{Ecto.LogEntry, :log, [:info]}]`.

**Update (by [@AndyMacKinlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30297825/disable-elixir-ecto-debug-output/30319577?noredirect=1#comment97459936_30319577)):**

Since Ecto 3.0.0, instead of `log_level: :info` you need to use `log: :info`.

**Update (by [@Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30297825/disable-elixir-ecto-debug-output/30319577?noredirect=1#comment118490370_30319577)):**

Since Ecto 3.0.0, you can also completely disable logging `log: false`.

Comment: This setting was changed in Ecto 2.0.0, instead of `log_level: :info` you need to use `loggers: [{Ecto.LogEntry, :log, [:info]}]`.

Comment: Milos, thanks. Can you make a new top-level answer for this?

Comment: You can also just stop Ecto from logging by setting the value of `loggers` to an empty list, as in `loggers: []`.

Comment: You need to use `log: :info` [in Ecto 3.0](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/3.0.7/Ecto.Repo.html#content)

Comment: I'm using Ecto 3.6 and apparently the new option is `:log: false` (this thread still shows high on Google searches). See the docs here https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#content

Answer (score 7):

To disable debug messages temporarily you can do `Logger.configure(level: :warn)` and then re-enable with `Logger.configure(level: :debug)`.

https://hexdocs.pm/logger/Logger.html#Levels

Comment: This is what I was looking for to be able to turn off debug in an `iex` session.

Comment: This is what I was looking for too.

Answer (score 6):

Ecto 3 answer to completely disabling logging would be:

```
config :app, App.Repo,
  username: "postgres",
  password: "postgres",
  database: "app_dev",
  log: false
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple put `loggers: []` in

`config :my_app, MyApp.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  database: "my_app_repo",
  username: "DB_USERNAME",
  password: "DB_PASSWORD",
  hostname: "DB_HOST",
  loggers: []`