# Debug level logging for `mix ecto.rollback` and `mix ecto.migrate` commands

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, elixir-mix

Currently, I'm looking for the way to add SQL-statements logging while running `mix` tasks. For example, commands such `mix ecto.rollback` and `mix ecto.migrate` outputs informative:

```
...
13:45:53.016 [info]  == Running Repo.Migrations.AddAmountToUserResources.change/0 backward
13:45:53.016 [info]  alter table user_resources
...
```

However instead of mysterious `alter table user_resources` I'd like to see exact SQL-statements generated by `ecto` which hits DB.
Is there any way to do that?

I've checked a couple of SO answers, which looks relevant (e.g. [Disable Elixir Ecto Debug output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30297825/disable-elixir-ecto-debug-output)). Unfortunately, they didn't help me in my case above.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A feature to allow logging raw SQL was added to Ecto [on 15 Jan 2017](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/pull/1885). There hasn't been a release of Ecto since then. Once there is, or you switch to using the version of Ecto from Github master branch, you can pass `--log-sql` to the commands `ecto.migrate` and `ecto.rollback` to make it log the complete query that's executed.

```
$ mix ecto.migrate --log-sql
$ mix ecto.rollback --log-sql
```

Comment: I've added `{:ecto, git: "git://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto.git", override: true}` into my `mix.exs`, after I have updated dependencies, and it works. `mix ecto.migrate --log-sql` now shows desirable debug statements. I think your answer will remain valid after that feature is released. Thanks.